# Lisp make-array from user input incorrect length

Tags: arrays, matrix, common-lisp

I am trying to load user input matrix to array in clisp:

```
(defvar *rows* (read))
(defvar *columns* (read))
(defvar *matrix* (read-line))
(setq m1 (make-array (list *rows* *columns*) :initial-contents *matrix*))
```

Input example:

```
2
3
((1 2 3) (4 5 6))
```

I get an error:

```
*** - MAKE-ARRAY: "((1 2 3) (4 5 6))" is of incorrect length
```

However, if I input it manually in the code:

```
(setq m1 (make-array '(2 3) :initial-contents '((1 2 3) (4 5 6))))
```

it works fine, what did I miss?

Comment: `read-line` is returning a string - one atom - when you type it you are quoting two lists of three atoms each.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want:

```
(setq m1 (make-array '(2 3) :initial-contents '((1 2 3) (4 5 6))))
```

But your code does something like this:

```
(setq m1 (make-array '(2 3) :initial-contents '"((1 2 3) (4 5 6))"))
```

Instead of a list structure of the initial contents, you pass in a string.

Convert the string to a list or use `read` instead of `read-line`.

Comment: …but do NOT use `read` on user input, or at least bind `*read-eval*` to `nil`.